# Problem in displaying objects from ForeignKey in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am having two models Patient and Ipd, Patient can have multiple Ipd. I am trying to get Patient Info in IpdForm but don't know where I am getting wrong

I have already tried "qs = Ipd.objects.get(patient__id=patient_id)" , "qs = Ipd.objects.filter(patient__id=patient_id)" but nothing worked

models.py :

```py
class Patient(models.Model): 

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200);
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20);
    address = models.TextField();
    Patient_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True);
    Gender= models.CharField(choices=GENDER, max_length=10)
    consultant = models.CharField(choices=CONSULTANT, max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name 

class Ipd(models.Model):

    reason_admission = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)
    presenting_complaints = models.CharField(max_length=200,)
    ipd_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    rooms = models.ForeignKey(Rooms,on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False)
    date_of_admission = models.DateField(("Date"),
        default=datetime.date.today)  
    patient = models.ForeignKey(Patient, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False, default = "")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.patient.name
```

forms.py :

```py
class PatientForm(forms.ModelForm):


    class Meta:
        model = Patient
        fields = ['name','phone','address','Patient_id','consultant','Gender']

class IpdForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Ipd

        fields = ['patient', 'reason_admission', 'presenting_complaints', 
                  'rooms', 'date_of_admission']
```

views.py:

```py
@login_required
def ipd (request,patient_id):
    formtwo = IpdForm()
    qs = Ipd.objects.filter(patient__Patient_id=patient_id)
    if request.method=="POST":

        formtwo = IpdForm(request.POST)

        if  formtwo.is_valid() :
            instance = formtwo.save(commit=False)
            instance.save
        else:
            return HttpResponse(formtwo.errors) 
    else:
        formtwo = IpdForm()
        return render(request, 'newipd.html', {'a':qs,'form2':formtwo})
```

urls.py :

```
url(r'^order/ipd/(?P<patient_id>\d+)/$', my_order.ipd, name='ipd'),
```

html :

```
<div class="card-panel">                                                 
<span class="blue-text text-darken-2">Name : {{ab.name}}</span> <br>                                                 
<span class="blue-text text-darken-2">Phone : {{ a.phone  }}</span><br>                                                  
<span class="blue-text text-darken-2">Address : {{ a.address  }}</span><br>                                              
<span class="blue-text text-darken-2">Gender : {{ a.Gender  }}</span><br>                                            
</div>
```

Comment: Your queryset is trying to get the wrong field. Should be `qs = Ipd.objects.filter(patient__id=patient_id)`

Comment: Sorry Sir, but I am having error " Related Field got invalid lookup: id "

Comment: @DanielRoseman Hello Sir! I think I was unable to explain the right problem of mine, I am having two form one creates patient object and another form is related to patient which contains patient info. I have not created any Ipd Object yet, that query will not work for that, I want to add patient object in my new Ipd Form ,Can You Help me with that I have been searching for an answer from a long time, Please Help Me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply access your Patient model by using

```
Ipd.objects.filter(patient_id=patient_id)
```

Note the single underscore at the first patient_id.

You only use double underscores while accessing a related model, but in this case you have a foreign key directly in your Ipd model.

**Edit**
I just saw, that you created your own Patient_Id field.
I would suggest to recreate your Patient model without the field Patient_id.
Django will create an ID field itself.

If you really want to keep your own field, than the correct access to it would be:

```
Ipd.objects.filter(patient_patient_id=patient_id)
```

But I would not recommend that.

There are a lot more flaws in your code, like keeping all fields lowercase in a model, etc.
Please try to refer to the Django docs and maybe Python docs.

Keeping you code clear would simplify a lot of things.

Comment: Sorry Sir, but Still not displaying data in IpdForm

Comment: Sorry  to disturb you again @normic but when I tried using my field patient_id , the problem is still there

Comment: @VickyRathod: I'm really not sure how Django works with model fields that contain capital letters. You should really recreate your model in accordance to Django docs. If it still not works, edit your post with your new code, and I'll recheck what might go wrong.